# How to add event handlers to HTML buttons from within JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a list of buttons (squares) in HTML like this -

```
  <td><button id="18" ></button></td>
  <td><button id="28" ></button></td>
  <td><button id="38" ></button></td>
           ...
```

Earlier, for each button, I had to put code within the button tag itself to add an event handler, like this:

```
  <button id="18" onclick="squareWasClicked(event)">

  function squareWasClicked(event)
   {
      var element = event.target; 

      // more code
   }
```

But now I have found out that it is not good practice. So instead, I am trying to add event handlers from within my JavaScript code. But I don't know how to do that. So far, I have tried this:

```
  function assignEventsToSquares()
   {
     var i,j;

     for(i=1;i<=8;i++)
      {
        for(j=1;j<=8;j++)
         {
           var squareID = "" + i + "" + j;
           var square = document.getElementById(squareID);        
           square.onclick = squareWasClicked(); 
         }
      }
   }
```

But this simply calls the `squareWasClicked()` function. So how do I add it as an event handler so that the function will be invoked when the square is clicked? Also, how do I say something like:

```
     square.onclick = squareWasClicked(event);
```

event is not detected in the JavaScript code. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
square.onclick = squareWasClicked();
```

This calls your click function and assigns the result to your element's event listener, which isn't what you want. Remove the `()`s so that the function itself gets assigned.
Hence, it should look like this

```
square.onclick = squareWasClicked;
```

Comment: Thanks! That was so concise! Why then is the addEventListener used? Is it older syntax?

Comment: `addEventListener` is a *newer* syntax (emerged in DOM 2, as opposed to DOM 0 listeners you are considering.) If you are not using DOM 2, you are missing out! :)

Answer (score 8):

Use [element.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) (originating from the [DOM 2 Events spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events)). In your case it will be

```
document.getElementById("18").addEventListener("click", squareWasClicked, false);
```

Comment: On a side note, according to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name), _"ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")."_

Comment: For older versions of IE (before IE9), you will need to use `attachEvent()` as they don't support `addEventListener`.

Comment: Right, there is a [cross-browser solution](http://dustindiaz.com/rock-solid-addevent) for this.

Comment: In the squareWasClicked() method, to access the button element, I am saying, var element = this;  Is that right?

Comment: No, to reference the element on which the event was dispatched, you should use `event.target` (also study the concept of event bubbling.) In event listeners, `this` will reference the global context (`window`) unless you pass in a bound function as a listener (i.e. `myFunc.bind(receiver, arg1, .., argN)`)